# HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>() get this InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I've used ASP.NET Identity 2 for creating a registration user logic, and I have an exception at HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager().

What could be a problem? Thank you for any advise.

**There is registration controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterUserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserManager logic**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store) 
        : base(store) 
{
    }
    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
                                            IOwinContext context)
    {
        IdentificationContext db = context.Get<IdentificationContext>();
        ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<AppUser>(db));
        return manager;
    }
}
```

**Registration model**

```
public class RegisterUserModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

Model that inherit from IdentitiyUSer model

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser() { }
}
```

**Startup class**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<IdentificationContext>(IdentificationContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        });
    }
```

There is an output of exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMKH1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add setting (owin:AutomaticAppStartup) in web.config

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
```

If it still doesn't work, add below setting specifying your startup class. This is because the default convention for the Startup class is [AssemblyName].Startup. If you're no longer following that convention you'll need to specify the full name of your Startup class in the Web.Config.

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[Namespace].Startup, [AssemblyName]" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, but it does not work, I have added:   
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[UserApp.App_Start].Startup, UserApp" /> and also tried to create a new Startup file the same fault. When I run my project I already have an exception at 'IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);' Do you have any another idea?

Comment: It seems earlier error was coming from line HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); and now it's coming from UserManager.CreateAsync(user);. Can you please post the new error message / stack trace here.

Comment: I add the code path with blue underlining where I get already exception when the project is running.

Comment: It seems code is fine. Double check value set in owin:AppStartup and also remove the square bracket from value. Also try by deleting Temporary ASP.Net files; Clean solution; Build and Run

Comment: it`s helped after deleting Temporary Asp.Net files, I have not an exception, thank you so much!